# Help with Linear Algebra proof that an infinite set of polynomials is independent

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

Let $\mu_k(t) = t^k$, for $k = 0,1,2, \dots,$ and $t$ is real. I want to show that the infinite set $S = \{\mu_0, \mu_1 , dots \}$ is independent. To do this, set up
(1) $\sum_{k=0}^n c_kt^k= 0$, for all real $t$.

Here's the part of the proof that I don't understand:

Putting $t=0$ in (1) we see that $c_0 = 0$. (Why? I don't see this, and it's my biggest stumbling block in the proof.) Now divide by $t$ in (1) and put $t=0$ again to find $c_1 = 0$. (So, I'm confused as to what is meant by $t$ in the proof. Is it all $t$? Also, why can we divide by $t$? Didn't we just say that $t=0$? Are there supposed to be subscripts?). Rinse and Repeat for the rest of the $c_k$.

I have one last question. The sum in (1) is finite. How does this prove that an infinite set is independent. Doesn't this show that only $n$ $\mu_i$'s are independent; rather than all $\mu_k$ for $k = 0, 1, \dots $ are independent.

Update 1: Why $t$ are we concerning ourselves with the case when $t=0$?

Comment: Because if you evaluate the function $t \mapsto t^k$ at $t=0$ the answer is $1$ for $k=0$ and $0$ for $k=1,...$.

Comment: No, $t$ is a specific $t \in \mathbb{R}$. It would be better to write $p(t) = \sum_k c_k t^k$. Then you want to show that if $p(t) = 0$ for **all** $t$, then $c_k = 0$. But note that $p(0) = \sum_k c_k 0^k = c_0$.

Comment: If a linear *dependence* relation holds among the infinitely many polynomials in your set, it only uses finitely many of them (dependence relations being finite sums to zero).  So if you show every finite subset is linearly independent, you prove the entire infinite set of polynomials is linearly independent.

Comment: An arbitrary set of elements is linearly independent **iff** any finite number of elements are linearly independent.

Comment: @copper.hat I'm confused by your first answer. What does it mean to evaluate $t \rightarrow t^k$ at $t=0$?

Comment: @copper.hat You're second comment is also confusing me. I'm not what I'm supposed to infer from it.

Comment: It means given the function $f(t)=t^k$, compute $f(0)$. For example, with $f(t) = t^2$, we have $f(0) = 0 \cdot 0 = 0$.

Comment: From my algebraic point of view the linear independence of the family $S$ is obvious, because each non-zero linear combination of its elements is a non-zero polynomial which cannot be a zero function, because it has only finitely many roots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's give our polynomial a name: define $p(t)=\sum_{k=0}^nc_kt^k$. We are assuming $p(t)=0$ for all real $t$, and we want to show that $c_0=\ldots=c_n=0$. Now note that
$$p(t)=c_0+c_1t+c_2t^2+\ldots+c_nt^n$$
We know that the left hand side is zero *for all* real $t$. In particular, it must be true when $t=0$, so substituting $t=0$ into the right hand side we find
$$0=p(0)=c_0+c_1\cdot0+\ldots+c_n\cdot0^n=c_0$$
Hence our polynomial is now
$$0=p(t)=c_1t+c_2t^2+\ldots+c_nt^n=t(c_1+c_2t+\ldots+c_nt^{n-1})$$
So either $t=0$ or $c_1+c_2t+\ldots+c_nt^{n-1}=0$. This implies $c_1+c_2t+\ldots+c_nt^{n-1}=0$ for all $t\neq0$, but by taking the limit as $t\to0$, it must be true at $t=0$ too! This follows from the continuity of polynomials. Now we just repeat this procedure until we have shown every $c_i=0$. An induction proof would probably be more rigourous, but I think at this level "repeat until there are no $c_i$'s left" is sufficient.

But why does this show $S$ is independent? As you pointed out, $S$ is infinite whereas we only looked at the first $n$ terms. However addition is only really defined on finitely many terms; if you have some topology you can sometimes define infinite sums but in the general vector space case this is not possible. So, the only sensible definition of $S$ being independent is that *every finite sum of $S$ is independent*. If we have a finite subset $F\subset S$, then in particular there is a largest $n$ such that $\mu_n\in F$. Hence the above argument applied for that particular $n$ shows $F$ is independent, and thus by definition (and the fact $F$ was an arbitrary finite subset) we find that $S$ is independent.

Comment: I'm still a little confused about setting t = 0. All that seems to follow is that IF $t$= 0, then all $c_i$'s must = 0. Don't we need to show that for all $t$, $c_i$ = 0.

Comment: The $c_i$'s are constant - they do not depend on $t$! So for these *constant* values $c_0,\ldots,c_n$ it is true *for all* $t$ that $c_0+\ldots+c_nt^n=0$. In particular, this is true when $t=0$, so we MUST have $c_0=0$. The reason we evaluate at zero is to eliminate all terms but one.

Answer (score 2):

If $V$ is a vector space over a field $F$ then a subset $A\subset V$ is *linearly independent* if any finite subset $\{a_1,a_2,\ldots, a_n\}\subset A$, $\>n\in{\Bbb N}_{\geq1}$, is linearly independent. Note that, in algebraic terms, it wouldn't make sense to check under what circumstances an infinite sum $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \lambda_k a_k$ is $\>=0$, since such a sum would not be defined in the first place.

In your example $V$ is the space of all polynomials in an indeterminate $t$ with real coefficients. It is a matter of convention whether you consider a polynomial

(I) as an infinite coefficient sequence $(c_0,c_1,c_2,\ldots)$
with only finitely many nonzero entries $c_k\in{\Bbb R}$,

or (II) as a function
$$p:\ {\Bbb R}\to{\Bbb R},\qquad t\mapsto \sum_{k=0}^{n_p} c_k t^k\ .$$
Under both views the monomials $\mu_k$ form a linearly independent set: Under (I) we have
$$\sum_{k=0}^N\lambda _k\mu_k=(\lambda_0,\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_N,0,0,\ldots)=0$$
iff all $\lambda_k=0$. Under (II) we have to prove that $$p(t):=\sum_{k=0}^N\lambda_k\>t^k\equiv0\tag{1}$$
implies $\lambda_k=0$ for all $k$. A quick proof is
$$\lambda_k={1\over k!}\>p^{(k)}(0)=0\qquad(0\leq k\leq N)\ .$$ 
A more algebraic proof would set up an induction as follows: $(1)$ implies $\lambda_0=p(0)=0$ and therefore
$p(t)=t\>p_1(t)$ with
$$p_1(t)=\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\lambda_{k+1}t^k\>\equiv0\ .$$
The induction hypothesis then guarantees $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=\ldots=\lambda_N=0$.